# CSRF Guard - Implementing it across .war files?

Tags: java, csrf

I have implemented CSRF Guard in one of the module of a project (`aaaa.war`) and it's working fine as excepted with in it. Now I have to implement the same in other modules also.

I have done the same steps in other `bbbb.war` file also (included `csrf.jar, js file, change the web.xml and properties file`) however in this case `tokenfromsession` is not matching because in the project there are calls from one `.war` file to another `.war` file. (might be the reason)

Any idea why I'm getting this or how can I fix this?

Is it possible to use the same implemented CSRF guard (`aaaa.war`) in other `bbbb.war` file also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not make your csrf guard abstracted to both of your wars and forward all requests to the csrf guard implementation then post the requests to the particular war.